# How to solve $ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^3 -y^3}{x-y}$ which is a seemingly homogenous equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

How to solve $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^3 -y^3}{x-y}?$$

I can show $\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2 +y^2 +xy,$ which may be converted into an exact differential or any other process might be helpful ?

Comment: I think you can introduce new variables u = x+y, v=x-y and transform the differential  equation into u,v equation.

Comment: This equation can not be solved by the known elementary functions

Comment: @Euduardo how do you write the numerator in terms of these functions?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Riccati equation, usually they are hard to solve unless you can see or guess a solution.

One can transform this into a second order linear DE using $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ leading to 
$$
\frac{-u''}{u}+\frac{u'^2}{u^2}=\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2+x\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)+x^2\\~\\
\implies u''-xu'+x^2u=0
$$
which by Mathematica/WolframAlpha has a normalized form with solutions by named functions (Hermite polynomials and Kummer hypergeometric functions) in the variable $z=\frac{\sqrt[4]3}2(1+i)x$.

Comment: Please elaborate how you got the second order differential equation?  I didn't find the substitution to find this.

Comment: I wrote the substitution directly above. Now with an additional step. It uses that $(e^v)''=e^v(v''+v'^2)$ to consume the quadratic term, here with $v'=-y$.